# Replacing #include using a header file in C

Tags: c

Sometimes it's just appropriate to write some fun code and sometimes it's just fun to write some unreadable code or some code with goto statements ;)

I was wondering if it's possible to replace `#include "stdio.h"` with some words of your choice using a header file?

If I attempt to do it, I get errors like

```
error: stray ‘#’ in program|
note: in expansion of macro ‘a’|
```

when I try something like "`#define a #include`" in my header file.

Comment: Big question. Why? ..................

Comment: Fun and it's always useful to find the borders of things possible

Comment: Hmm, `goto` statements are pretty much *standard practice* if you look at the source files for the standard C functions -- but, then again, they are still fun -- and useful for short jumps out of nested code blocks.

Comment: "`stray ‘#’`" is common. What is the canonical question?

Comment: For ***UTF-8 sequences***, the canonical question  is *[Compilation error: stray ‘\302’ in program, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198332/compilation-error-stray-302-in-program-etc)*.

Answer (score 3):

> I get errors like
>
> error: stray ‘#’ in program|
>
> note: in expansion of macro ‘a’|
>
> when I try something like "#define a #include " in my header file.

Preprocessing directives are identified at the start of translation phase 4 (C2011, 6.10/2), before any macro expansions are performed.  Thus, although you can define a macro `a` with expansion `#include`, the expansion is not a preprocessing directive, neither at that point (because it's not the first token on the line) nor when the macro is expanded (because that's too late).

As a result, using such a macro results in the literal text `#include` appearing in the preprocessor output, and that's not valid C at any point where an ordinary `#include` directive could validly appear.

Comment: Also what is better/clearer than `#include "stdio.h"` ... nothing? Seems pretty clear.

Comment: @Ben, I don't think the OP is looking for better; I think he's looking for perverse.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any way to replace the way you include header files in a C program, is part of the standard unless you write your own compiler you can make it work as you want.

Answer (score 0):

The normal way would be to use conditional inclusion:

```c
#ifdef TEST
  #include "test.h"
#endif
```

As for what's allowed in the include directive itself, it has two standard forms `#include <stdio.h>` with `<>`, which searches library paths, and  `#include "myheader.h"` which searches the default project path (and then if not found there, it tries library paths too).

The C standard (C17 6.10.2) allows a third form however:

> `# include` *pp-tokens new-line*

Where "pp-tokens" is a sequence of pre-processor tokens. The same section  states that "The directive resulting after all replacements shall match one of the two previous forms", referring to the `<>` and `""` versions.

This means that we *can* write obscure code like this:

```c
#define STDIO <stdio.h>
#include STDIO
```

But it is unlikely a good idea to do so and I've personally never had a need to use this trick. Some programmers have a habit of using includes as a way to insert long initialize lists etc into the program and maybe that's one potential use for this feature.

Managing build-related things from the C pre-processor is overall not a good idea since it clutters up the code. Leave that to the version control system and the IDE/make files.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean this?

#### File *yams.c*

```
int main()
{
#define STDIO_H <--- without this define I still get yams!
    printf("yams\n");
    return 0;
}
```

#### Build

```
# Make yams
cc     yams.c   -o yams
```

Output:

```
yams.c: In function ‘main’:
yams.c:6:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’
     printf("yams\n");
     ^
```

#### Run

```
./yams
```

Output:

```
yams
```

I am confused =P

So does stdio need to be included/defined constantly? Or does the compiler chuck it in automatically?

### Another example

Using scanf:

#### File *scanned_yams.c*

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    scanf("%d", i);
}
```

#### Build

```
make scanned_yams
```

Output:

```
cc     scanned_yams.c   -o scanned_yams
scanned_yams.c: In function ‘main’:
scanned_yams.c:6:2: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘scanf’
  scanf("%d", i);
  ^
```

#### Run

```
./scanned_yams
```

There is clearly something very wrong with me.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the difference between the header `<stdio.h>` and the standard library is automatically linked.  That provides the function definitions, even if the functions were not properly declared.  Whether the code works depends on the compiler; usually, it happens to.  However, all this is tangential to the question, I believe.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler , okay neat, so stdio.h is what then, something like specific settings definitions outside of the standard library?

Comment: The header `<stdio.h>` defines necessary types and macros, and declares the functions required by the standard (plus any extensions that the implementation chooses to provide).  That's its job — to make the information available to the compiler.  The linker then takes the object files created from your source code and the pre-compiled implementation of the library and creates an executable that you can run.