# Arduino IDE - Strange #endif without #if when copying library code to sketch folder

Tags: arduino, compilation, arduino-ide

I'm implementing an [IoT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_of_things) device using the [Espalexa](https://github.com/Aircoookie/Espalexa) library on a Wemos D1 R1 board. I wanted to make some modifications on the library code, so I copied the library files from the Arduino libraries folder to my [sketch](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Sketch) directory to perform those modifications on the copy. I changed the library header file name in order to avoid conflicts with the library (from file *Espalexa.h* to file *Espalexamod.h*), but now it won't compile, giving me this unexpected error.

First of all, by compiling using the library included as <Espalexa.h> everything works fine, while after trying to compile the following sketch:

```cpp
#include "Espalexamod.h"

void setup() {
  // Put your setup code here, to run once:

}

void loop() {
  // Put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

It gives me the following, unexpected error:

```
C:\path\to\sketch\Espalexamod.h:610:2: error: #endif without #if
  610 | #endif
      |  ^~~~~
exit status 1

Compilation error: #endif without #if
```

Specifically, this is the last #endif in the code (the one closing the guard define). I also tried changing the guard define to another name and check that all defines were closed on the code (but this was obvious since by using the library normally, everything works fine).

As a last try, I commented the #endif on the file and after compiling it gave another unexpected error

```
C:\bath\to\sketch\Espalexamod.h:1:1: error: '<?>' does not name a type
    1 | <?>#ifndef Espalexa_h
      |

exit status 1

Compilation error: stray '#' in program
```

where <?> is actually a diamond question mark symbol, so it seems that this time it correctly recognizes the final #endif as needed (because it's needed!).

I'm really going crazy after this. I also tried with IDE 1.x and 2.x, and I tried deleting the build cache and creating a new sketch from scratch, but nothing seems to work.

How can I fix it?

Comment: PS: i forgot to mention that all these errors appear before making any modification on the copyed files, just the header file name was changed (but also without changing it, they manifest)

Comment: A canonical for stray characters is *[Compilation error: stray ‘\302’ in program, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198332/compilation-error-stray-302-in-program-etc)*. Though "`stray '#' in program`" probably deserves its own canonical question.

Comment: Related (UTF-16 big endian BOM induced—signature "377"): *[How should I use g++'s -finput-charset compiler option correctly in order to compile a non-UTF-8 source file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10345802/how-should-i-use-gs-finput-charset-compiler-option-correctly-in-order-to-com)*

Comment: Same symptom (UTF-8 BOM induced?), *"error: stray ‘#’ in program"*: *[Replacing #include using a header file in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34644520/replacing-include-using-a-header-file-in-c/34644748#34644748)*

Comment: cont' - Probably not. It seems to be just some (rather useless) play with the preprocessor.

Comment: But a combination of a [UTF-8 BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) and a preprocessor thing in the very first line can't be that rare.

Comment: There are [110 questions linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/19198332?lq=1) to the mentioned canonical. Perhaps it is in there somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The <?> doesn't belong.  That error is preventing `#ifndef Espalexa_h` from being seen.  So when you reach the `#endif` then there was no previous if because that `#ifndef` didn't get read.

Comment: Thanks you for the answer! I also was slowly coming to that conclusion, and run a format-hex command on the source file, it actually had three bytes at the beginning (EF BB BF) preventing the #ifndef to be correcly read, after removing those characters it worked! I still don't understand why using the file from Arduino library folder it works fine (those characters were also on that file) but i suppose that we must see this of another mistery of the Arduino IDE. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I found out that in this specific file, there are [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) bytes at the beginning (EF BB BF).

It seems that the Arduino-IDE doesn't go well with them. After removing those bytes, it compiles normally. It remains a mystery why it compiles from the library folder, but not from the local folder.

[Here](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/compiler-error-about-stray-characters/1042516) they had a similar problem with the BOM and a user posted a solution to convert the file encoding to delete those bytes.

Comment: The Arduino IDE doesn't add a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) to the source files, at least not on Linux and Arduino IDE version 1.8.19. It was tested with creating a new blinky (menu *File* → *Examples* → *01. Basics* → *Blink*) and immediately saving it (to a new file).

Comment: What is the specific file? The third-part file `Espalexa.h`? Or something else?

Comment: Yes, the BOM was not added by the IDE, it's already present on Espalexa.h on the repository (see the hyperlink on "Espalexa" on my original question")

Comment: This was also already present on the library downloaded from Arduino repository (i copied it from there) and indeed the strange thing is that it compiles if espalexa is included from the libraries folder (<Espalexa.h>) but not copying the file on the sketch folder and including it from there.